# Send Website Data to an Excel File Uploaded in Sharepoint

Tags: excel, web, sharepoint

Is possible to directly send a website data (like a text in a textbox) to an Excel file uploaded in Sharepoint?

Like when a textbox value is `John Doe`, the value will be sent to a column in Excel automatically. I've searched for this on the Internet but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [su] because it is not a programming question.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller quite the opposite, it requires an API, similar to how Google Sheets works, but more complex. That's different between on-prem and online versions though. Older versions of SharePoint [had a REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/excel-services-rest-api). SharePoint and Excel in Microsoft 365 use MS Graph as the starting point. Unfortunately, it's hard to find an easy-to-use way to do what the user asks

Comment: You are asking about how to program a web site that you control to send the data?

Comment: I'm not the OP. I'm the former SharePoint MVP. As written, this is a programming question but the answer isn't easy. If this was about Google Sheets I'd point to the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) docs. With Office 365 - where do you even start?

Comment: @Heder are you using SharePoint on-premises or SharePoint Online? If on-prem, what version?

Comment: For Online, you can probably use the [Excel workbooks and charts API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/excel-concept-overview) and [Write data to an Excel workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/excel-write-to-workbook) guides. SharePoint is used as the backend for online Excel sheets, so the guides should apply. The `Write Data` has examples for ASP.NET, Angular, React